# How does an inherited member function in C++ work with children member variable?

Tags: c++, inheritance

For instance, I have base class A:

```
class A {
public:
    callA() {
        val = 100;
        std::cout << this->val << std::endl;
    }
    int val;
}

class B : public A {
    public:
    B() {
        val = 10;
    }
    int val;
}

B b;
b.callA();
```

What will `b.callA()` print?

And for B inheriting A, if B does not have a field val, will B share an exact reference to A's val, or is it a copy?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no point in asking what the output will be when it's simple to run and see

Comment: It prints 100. Is this unexpected?

Comment: You have two different member variables. The fact that they have the same name is not important. You would get exactly the same result if `B` used `another_val`, for example.

Comment: Why do you do `this->val` for `cout`, but `val = ` for assignment?  You should be more consistent and drop the `this->val`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, any instance of Class B contains an entire copy of Class A. In fact, when you initialize a new instance of Class B, Class A's constructor is run first. Therefore, when you call a non-virtual function from the base class, it will run as if it were run from the base class, which is internal to the derived class. It can even access the private variables of the base class (which the derived class wouldn't be able to access, it only has access to public/protected variables from the base class).

[Example](http://ideone.com/Oza6Nx):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:

   A()
   {
      cout << "Base constructor!" << endl;

      privateVar = 10;
   }

   void testPrint()
   {
      cout << "privateVar: " << privateVar << endl;
   }

private:

   int privateVar;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   B()
   {
      cout << "Derived Constructor!" << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   B testB;
   testB.testPrint();

   return 0;
}
```